# Using a high-res image for a custom swipe mechanism in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` where the `UITableViewCell` is dynamic and inheriting from a custom `UITableViewCell` class. I have introduced a swipe gesture on the cell to favourite the cell, but I'm having a bit of issues with the image that shows when the cell is swiped.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

On anything but the iPhone 5s, it looks pixelated and terrible. The image is currently a square image of size **50x50**.

If I upped the size to **200x200**, I get:

[image]

This looks less pixelated, but also at the same time looks absolutely terrible.

In my `cellForRow`, this is the code I am using to apply the image:         `[self.rightUtilityButton sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:`

```
 [UIColor orangeColor] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star.png"]];
```

I am using the SWTableViewCell open source code (https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) as my reference for this, but I can't find in the code where this size is actually set on the UITableViewCell custom image and I can't get in touch with the author.

**Issues**

I basically want to use the **200x200** image, but in the frame size of the **50x50** image. How can I force this? Perhaps I can put the **200x200** image into another `UIImageView` with a clear background? If that is the way, I'm not sure how to achieve it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include multiple resolutions for the same image and use the @nx naming scheme.

For example: You have set the imageView as 50 x 50 px in the interface builder or code.
For the above imageView, you should provide the following images:

```
star.png    - 50x50 px   (For screens with scale 1 resolution like in iPhone 3GS, iPad 2)
star@2x.png - 100x100 px (For screens with scale 2 resolution like in iPhone 4s - iPhone 6)
star@3x.png - 150x150 px (For screens with scale 3 resolution like in iPhone 6S)
```

Then, simply set the image for the imageView as:

```
[imageView setImage:@"star"]; //Dont use the extension
```

At this point, the app will automatically pick up the best image based on the current screen and show the right image.

Comment: Thanks @zemoon - that's really helpful. Where do I place that code to set the star.png and star@2x.png, etc. Also, would that still bring up the huge star on devices like the 6 Plus?

Comment: Just using the name @"star" will resolve to star@2x on iPhone 4S and star@3x on iPhone 6S

Comment: Thanks @zeMoon - that does work and it detects the differences, but just like in my question, the 6Plus is using the HUGE image - i.e. It looks like a massive star, so it's now definitely using the right image because I removed the .png as well and have changed the background colour per device to make sure, but it just looks terrible on the 6 Plus as per the question. Is there anyway I can force the size of the star in the view and then continue to use this technique of selecting the appropriate image.

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8

Comment: I've read that - but it just doesn't make too much sense to me. I'm sorry, basically, is there anyway I can take this star UIImage and draw place it in a UIImageView and specify the size of it? I'm sorry I'm not getting this.

Comment: You should provide the same gap around the new images as well

Comment: Also, set the UIImageView's scale mode to Aspect Fit

Comment: Are you able to quickly chat about this?(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96422/discussion-between-amitsbajaj-and-zemoon).

Comment: It's a UIImage, not a UIImageView I'm using.. Should I be using UIImageView?

Comment: How are you showing the image if not inside a UIImageView?

Comment: With this code:     
    
    self.rightUtilityButton = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.rightUtilityButton sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor orangeColor] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Star"]];

Comment: I'm sorry - I've achieved this by just adjusting the image canvas. Thanks for your help and sorry it was just back and fourth!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped :)